# Relatioship between Weight of inner product on Hilbert space and elements

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

So I was wondering say you have a Hilbert such as the inner product is defined as $$ <f,g>= \int fge^{-x^2}dx $$ where $ f,g \in M  $ where $M$ is the set of functions on which the inner product is defined.

Now say you have a mapping such as $$ \phi :M \rightarrow M' $$ $$ f \rightarrow e^{-x^2/2}f $$

and you have a inner product defined such as $$ <f,g>=\int fgdx $$

Where $ f,g \in M' $. So I was wondering what would the relation be between these two Hilbert spaces then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $T\colon M\to M'$ by $(Tf)(x)=e^{-x^2/2}f(x)$. ClearThen, for amy $f,g\in M$ we have
$$
\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\,g(x)\,e^{-x^2}\,dx=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\,e^{-x^2/2}\,g(x)\,e^{-x^2/2}\,dx=\langle Tf,Tg\rangle.
$$
Since clearly $T$ is bijective, $T$ is an isometry and $M$ and $M'$ are isometric.

Comment: Thx, I see that, however I think my question now is more like, can we consider these spaces equivalent? Is isometry the equivalence relation on Hilbert spaces?

Comment: It is certainly an equivalence relation. Do you know that all Hilbert spaces of the same _dimension_ (with the appropriate definition of dimension for the infinite dimensinal case) are equivalent?